# Can not generate build-info.properties file trough the maven command clean install

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I can't see the file `build-info.properties` in the folder `target/classes/META-INF` when i execute the command `mvn clean install` or `mvn package`. But to get it i should execute `mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-info` but it contains the default properties and not the additional one of java version!

How can i let my spring boot project generates this file with the `mvn clean install` command ?

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProperties>
                      <java.source>11</java.source>
                    </additionalProperties>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but since there is no answer and that I've run in this problem lately, here's my solution.

In my experience, it works only if you **don't** use the "clean" at the same time, i.e. do

`mvn clean`
and then
`mvn install`
instead of
`mvn clean install`

Actually, the "compile" goal is enough to generate the file build-info.properties.